# Скрипт на проверку занятости js

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт где возможно выбрать страну-регион-город

```html
            <label for="country_id">Выберите страну:</label><br/>
            <select name="country_id" id="country_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
                <option value="0">- выберите страну -</option>
                <option value="3159">Россия</option>
            </select><br/>
            <label for="region_id">Выберите регион:</label><br/>
            <select name="region_id" id="region_id" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
                <option value="0">- выберите регион -</option>
            </select><br/>
            <div id="frmCheckname">
            <label for="name">Выберите город:</label><br/>
            <select name="name" id="name" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
                <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
            </select><br/>
            <input class="demoInputBox" onBlur="checkAvailability()"><span id="user-availability-status"></span>
            </div>
```

```js
    <script>
function checkAvailability() {
 $("#loaderIcon").show();
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "/wp-content/themes/classipress-v3.5.1/check_availability.php",
 data:'name='+$("#name").val(),
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
  $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
  $("#loaderIcon").hide();
 },
 error:function (){}
 });
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );

if(!empty($_POST["name"])) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE first_name='" . $_POST["name"] . "'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $user_count = $row[0];
  if($user_count>0) {
      echo "<br /><span class='status-not-available'> Размещение рекламы в этом городе не доступно.</span>";
  }else{
      echo "<br /><span class='status-available'> Размещение рекламы в этом городе доступно.</span>";
  }
}
?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы данный код работал в select
В данный момент ошибка **Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in**

Comment: надо составить правильно запрос к БД так, чтоб он вернул ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверять возвращаемые ошибки

```
$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE first_name='" . $_POST["name"] . "'"
);
if (!$result)
  die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($row === false)
  die('Empty set');
$user_count = $row[0];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков поправил. После `die` забыл `;`

Comment: Спасибо была банальная ошибка не существующая колонка first_name